# Factorization - Quadratic terms

Tags: matrices

Is it possible to factorize the following matrix?

\begin{equation}
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
q_1^2 \\
q_2^2 \\
q_3^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

-- Edited --

I am wondering if I might write the matrixn in terms of $q = \begin{bmatrix} q_1 \\ q_2 \\ q_3\end{bmatrix}$ in an ellegant manner.

Best regards.

Comment: At the current moment I work with theoretical mechanics. The matrices are written in terms of $q$ as defined in the question. Define $Q$ would be, although possible, slightly annoying aesthetically. But if it take much effort to factorize it, I thank you sincerely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you'd like to use, so I propose e.g.
$$Q=\sum_{i=1}^3 \left({e}_i^T,{q}\right)^2 {e_i},$$

- where $e_1^T=(1,0,0)$ and similarly $e_2^T, e_3^T,$ are row vectors,
- $ \left({e}_i^T,{q}\right)$ is a dot product (scalar product) of the vectors

I assumed the vector $q$ has real coordinates.

Comment: It suits me. Thank you very much ^^

Comment: If you may define a function to generate a vector of such fashion $Q = f(q)$, what name would you give to it?

Comment: I would call it $Q = \mathbb{2}(q)$